# Как установить SSL сертификат на сервер Ubuntu при работе с Nginx?

Tags: ssl

У меня есть сервер на котором стоит nginx и там необходимо нацепить SSL сертификат от Name.com я пытался сделать по их инструкции которую они прислали мне на почту, но ничего не вышло. Поэтому прошу помощи здесь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для установки SSL на ваш Ubuntu сервер необходимо иметь Private Key а так-же сертификат с рассширением crt, желательно что-бы сертификат был подписан и одобрен центроом сертификации DigiCert или похожими поставщиками. Далее будет необходимо загрузить 2 этих файла на ваш сервер, т.к ваш сервер использует nginx то папка хранения файлов с сертификатами и ключами это: /etc/nginx/ssl/

Далее будет необходимо указать путь до сертификата и ключа в конфиге сайта nginx. Затем вводите команды по очереди:
"systemctl stop nginx" "systemctl start nginx" "systemctl restart nginx" "nginx" если у вас выходят ошибки по типу: [image: изображение ошибки]

Повода для беспокойства нету(это происходит из-за если не ошибаюсь много кратного прослушивания нескольких или одного порта)

Так-же даю ссылки на полезные источники:

https://ssl.com.ua/faq/how-to-install-ssl-nginx.html

- Установка если вам не пойдет моё объяснение

https://zerossl.com/
бесплатный SSL(когда-нибудь пригодится:D)

Comment: Всё работает спасибо!

Comment: Пользуйтесь Удачи!